# enforcing Parentheses after method name in Python class

Tags: python, methods

For a simple example in a Python class, I want to have a method that doubles a number given by the user, when it is run.
    The method does its job or purpose when used with parentheses, but when the method is used without parentheses,
     it doesn't do its job of doubling the number, and the main problem is that the interpreter doesn't raise an error or complain either.
    it is assumed by the user nothing went wrong and the code is run wrongly undetected.
    **how to rewrite a method in a class (here "double()") to force class user always put parentheses at the end, otherwise it raises an error?!**

```
>>> class Number(): 
         def __init__(self,number):  
           self.number = number  
         def double(self):  
           self.number = self.number * 2


>>> num = Number(10)  
>>> num.number  
10  
>>> num.double    ## method does nothing when used without parantheses, and it only shows a class method  
<bound method Number.double of <__main__.Number object at 0x03B04460>>  
>>> num.number    ## the number value has not changed  
10  
>>> num.double()   ## method does its purpose right  
>>> num.number     ## now the number has been doubled   
20
```

Comment: You're looking at this the wrong way i feel. The blame is absolutely on the user/programmer of the code if they don't "call" a function/method. That's literally on them to make sure they call things!

Comment: having said that, perhaps you can add an indicator that does show that the doubling happened, using a print statement inside the `.double()` method as an indicator for the end user.

Comment: I don't think it's possible... maybe with a Python linting tool, or if you "monkey patch" classes or something, but then you have to load that monkey patch before the students execute their code.

Answer (score 1):

The language allows to take reference to a method so what you're asking is not possible. It's always legal to do `num.double` because you could store the reference in a variable for later use for instance.

```
a = num.double
a()   # calling the method
```

In cases like this you could make it so calling `num.double` actually does something, using a *property* decorator.

```
 @property
 def double(self):
   self.number = self.number * 2
```

now

```
n = Number(21)
n.double
print(n.number)
>>> 42
```

But properties are more used to mimic attributes. And a python coder stumbling on that construct would have a tough time figuring it out, so I guess it's better to get used to the `()` convention.

Answer (score 0):

In python, and many other languages, you use the parenthesis to call a function, if you don't place them, you are only naming the function not actually asking it to be executed.

A user doesn't have to know this, that's why the input method exist. Try something like this:

```
number = int(input('write the number you want to double: '))
print(number*2)
```

or if you want to use your code:

```
class Number(): 
         def __init__(self,number):  
           self.number = number  
         def double(self):  
           self.number = self.number * 2

number = int(input('write the number you want to double: '))
myNum = Number(number)
myNum .double()
print(myNum)
```

Answer (score 0):

Configure your text editor/IDE to add an opening parentheses automatically when it detects that you typed/autocompleted an attribute name that looks like a function name.

If the editor detected wrong, and you actually want to work with the unbound method/function object, you can just backspace to delete the parentheses; and if you actually want to call, you can add the closing parentheses. The auto parens makes it an explicit decision whether to add or not add parentheses, and it would remind you that the attribute needs to get called to take effect when you're editing it as it can't be easily missed.